# Nowrap inheritance bug in IE6 (and earlier version)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have some task to make a carousel, that would holds several elements with not defined width. So, the easiest way — to make all elements in row by CSS and then do all JS calculations and so on. All was going well before testing it in (bug producer) IE6.

Here the sample what is going on in browsers:

Safari (5.1.2), Firefox (10.0.2), Opera (11.62)
[image: Safari 5.1.2]

Internet Explorer (9.1)
[image: Internet Explorer 9.1]

**Internet Explorer (6)** (Text in span bump li box)
[image: Text in span bump li box — Internet Explorer 6]

DebugBar about LI, it's ignoring preset rule **white-space: normal** — Internet Explorer 6
[image: DebugBar about LI — Internet Explorer 6]

DebugBar about SPAN, it's ignoring inheritance preset rule **white-space: normal** — Internet Explorer 6
[image: DebugBar about SPAN — Internet Explorer 6]

Here sample of HTML:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="box">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Some text</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Some longer text</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        …
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here part of CSS that manage it:

```
div.carousel {
  width: 700px; height:200px;
  }
  div.carousel div.box {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    div.carousel div.box ul {
      display: block; 
      white-space: nowrap; /* to make all inside elements lay in row */
      }
      div.carousel div.box ul li {
        margin-left: 23px;
        width: 130px; height: 150px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        white-space: normal;
        }
```

box correction for IE6 and earlier:

```
div.carousel div.box ul li {
  display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  }
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCuJT/73/) in jsFiddle

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of IE6. (but seriously, you're not really worried about versions older than that, are you???)

Comment: of course not, IE6 is end of my possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this url: http://cos.livejournal.com/36490.html

The answer, it seems it our old favourite, Quirks Mode. In Quirks Mode, IE does not recognise the `white-space:normal` style, but does recognise the other `white-space` styles, hence your cascading problem.

The solution is to stop IE going into quirks mode. This is as simple as adding a valid Doctype to the start of your page.

Quirks mode will likely introduce other layout glitches to your page as well, so this one fix should solve others problems you may have too.